# Webpack 4 not loading images from HTML files

Tags: html, css, image-processing, webpack-4

For some reason my webpack configuration is loading the images that comes from my SCSS files but not the ones that come from the HTML files. Also when I run the BUILD command in order to deliver my prod archives it does not create the "img" folder. To be honest I'm pretty new with webpack 4 and I guess there's a couple of steps that I'm not including on the WP config file.

This is my webpack.dev.js

This is the prod folder structure that I would want to create:

dist

|----img

|----css

|----js

a.html

b.html

c.html

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/js/scripts.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "js/[name].[hash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ["url-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 8080
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin("dist", {}),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "css/style.[contenthash].css"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      inject: false,
      hash: true,
      filename: "index.html"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/actualitat.html",
      inject: false,
      hash: true,
      filename: "actualitat.html"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/projectes.html",
      inject: false,
      hash: true,
      filename: "projectes.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

This is the way im loading both css and js on my html files:

```
    <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.main.css %>"
/>

<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.main.entry %>"></script>
```

I have a "scripts.js" js file where I import the files like this:

```
import "../scss/style.scss";
import "../img/searchBar-icon.png";
import "../img/townHall.png";
import "../img/icon-title.png";
```

**UPDATE:**

I have change the way im loading images using the "file-loader" loader:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: {
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        outputPath: "img/",
        name: "[name][hash].[ext]"
      }
    }
  }
```

Now all of my images are being copied to the "img" folder which is good,  problem is that all the names of the files have hashes now (which make sense since I'm telling the loader to add them) and they're not loading on my html files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following for loading the images?

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$/i,
  use: ["file-loader?name=[name].[hash].[ext]"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Manikanta Prasanth but with the change suggested i only get hashes on my images and now not even the ones that come from the SASS files are loading.